# Change MUI Text color of TextField Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So the code is this:

```
                        <TextField
                          required
                          id="outlined-select-currency"
                          select
                          label="Client Type"
                          value={currency}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          sx={{ '& input' : {color: 'white'}, '& label.Mui-focused': { color: 'white' }, '& label' : {color: 'white'} }}
                        >
                          {currencies.map((option) => (
                            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}
                            >
                              {option.label}
                            </MenuItem>
                          ))}
                        </TextField>
```

and the result is **this:**

[image] [image]

But when you select from the dropdown you get this:

[image]

Does anyone know what class should I override to change the text color?
(on other  the sx{} work just fine, but here using the  it doesn't.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name is `.MuiInputBase-input` on which you can set `color: "yourColor"`

```
<TextField             
    sx={{ '& .MuiInputBase-input': { color: 'white' } }}
/>
```